# force htcondor to use a single machine without explicitly specifying it

Tags: parallel-processing, condor

I want to submit a locally parallelized job to htcondor, e.g. it will use 10 CPUS and 100G RAM in total. It can run on any machine.

How do I ask htcondor to allocate these resources on a single machine without specifying a machine explicitly using something like `Machine == "machine1"` which will restrict it to that specific machine?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do, and what you think is the problem? HTCondor will by default always use resources of only one slot, which represents at most a single machine. Does your HTCondor cluster have partitionable slots, or are all resource statically partitioned? Is there any single slot large enough to run your job?

Comment: Thanks @MisterMiyagi As far as I know (I did not setup the cluster), there is no single slot that can run the job so I need to ask for multiple slots but they must be on the same machine so that my parallelization works properly. Does this clarify the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your administrator has set up partitionable slots in HTCondor, you can just add
`request_cpus = 10` to your condor submit file, and condor will run the job in a 10-core large slot on one machine.